# EF generated SQL query returns empty result when querying datetime column, but the record exists in database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

I have a very simple SQL Server database table with `datetime` primary key:

[image: Table with datetime primary key]

I generated EF model and database context for this table:

```cs
[Table("Test")]
public partial class Test
{
    public DateTime Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public partial class Model : DbContext
{
    public Model() : base("name=Model") { }
    public virtual DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }
}
```

There is a record with `Id = 2016-09-21 15:20:01.003` in `Test` table. Let's try to read that record using EF context:

```cs
var data = context.Test
    .Where(o => o.Id == new DateTime(2016, 09, 21, 15, 20, 01, 003))
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(data.Count); // data.Count = 0 here!
```

EF returns 0 records even if the database record with such ID exists. This is a generated EF SQL query:

```sql
-- This query produces an empty result
SELECT 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
  FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE convert(datetime2, '2016-09-21 15:20:01.0030000', 121) = [Extent1].[Id]
```

As you can see, EF converts `DateTime` value from the `Where` method predicate to `datetime2` SQL type. And indeed, this query returns an empty result set.

If I remove the conversion and change the date to match `datetime` type format (i.e., remove trailing zeroes), the query works as expected:

```sql
-- This query returns existing record
SELECT 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[Value] AS [Value]
  FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [Extent1]
  WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = '2016-09-21 15:20:01.003'
```

I understand that changing my `Id` column's type to `datetime2` will solve the problem (actually, Microsoft [recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) using `datetime2` for all new development). But I'm still curious, is this behavior a bug or by design in Entity Framework? Is there a way to make it work with `datetime` underlying SQL type?

Comment: You probably should avoid to have float or real (datetimes are rapresented with floats and reals on various databases) as primary keys on tables. You don't have portability and you have issues like this very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is by design.

**Reason:** if you not set any value to the datetime field then EF will send 1.1.0001 as a default value.That value **cannot be** handled using the SQL datetime type. That is why EF team recommends to use datetime2 as a data type on the SQL server.

The latest version of EF that is EF core **does not support SQL Server 2005**, but it supports 2008 and forward.Due to same reason which I have mentioned above. In other words there is no datetime2 data type on the SQL server 2005.

Comment: But how this fact prevents EF from generating the correct query for `datetime` data type?

Comment: B'cos `EF` knows only about `datetime2`.that is why it tries to convert it to `datetime2`. It's by design.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, whereas DateTime is *good for using as index* it is *not recommended* to use them as primary keys. Secondly you can try setting type of property to avoid conversion:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{ 
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>()
        .Property(m => m.Id)
        .HasColumnType("datetime");
}
```

Comment: Just tried `HasColumnType("datetime")` and it doesn't affect generated SQL query - result is still empty.